Cannot find where can I set up a special email when user request change password using an invalid IP
When an user request change password from a standard forget password page and their IP address wasn't added into its profile IP Login Ranges, the user will receive an email telling that their change password request failed, because their IP wasn't included in approved IP list and ask the user for checking with the admin about this.
And we didn't find where we can config this on our sandbox (we have tried search this in metadata, manually check in Classic Email Templates, query all EmailTemplate in SOQL...
